# In our neck of the woods

Tags: meaning-in-context

> In our neck of the woods, most Indians tend to include two or three chapattis as part of the main course.

source: "New Beginnings", by LimeyLady.

"In our neck of the woods"-what does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

"In our neck of the woods" is a phrase that refers to the area where the speaker lives. Similarly, one could say "Where we come from..." instead.